# "Future finite" conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions

How do we say that something will be done in the future only if something else has been done in the past.

For example:

> Tom will receive money if he **had filled** in the form*

or should that be **have filled**, **have had filled** or something else entirely?

If possible, when providing an answer, can you explain the rule(s) that should be applied in such cases..

Answer (score 1):

In general:

> He will receive money if he fills in the form.

If you're talking about something that has *actually* happened in the past, then you could say:

> He filled in the form, so he will receive money.

If you're wondering if something has been done or not:

> If he has filled in the form, he will receive money.

If you know that they *haven't* done something, but want to express what would have happened if they had:

> If he had filled in the form, he would have received money.

---

Note that I standardized on *he* as the pronoun (it's the gender you used) rather than pairing *one* with the singular *they* as I'd originally thought to phrase the answer.

Comment: You might explain why the first example is the best option without further context, solving the issues of gender mismatch and use of perfect tenses in the original.

Comment: @user3169 The first example *isn't* the best option. That was just a "baseline" sentence construction—a simple statement. The other sentences are examples of different tenses, all equally valid for their individual contexts. (Perhaps I shouldn't have left *one* in the first sentence—but it's still valid.)

Comment: What I was trying to say... You might add why you changed "he" to "they" and why a perfect tense in a basic sense isn't necessary (why make things more complicated without a reason?). These might help the OP's understanding.